# Zip and Tar compress entire top directory and not (sub)directory

Tags: linux, zip, tar

I'm trying to only zip the directory where I am exactly, this is part of a bigger bash script so I need to cd into the directory where I want to extract files and then exit.

However, using either tar or zip, the entire top directory path is recreated and not just the subdirectory that I'm interested in.

I get the following error:

```
zip warning: name not matched: $PWD/*
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
#Sub Directory and contents will be compressed
cd "$Sub_Dir"

Zipped_Files=$(basename "$Sub_Dir")
zip -r "$Zipped_Files".zip "$PWD/*" 
#or
zip -j "$Zipped_Files".zip "$PWD/*" 
#or
#tar -zcf "$Zipped_Files".zip "$PWD"
echo "Files have been compressed"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already `cd` into the sub dir, `zip -r "$Zipped_Files".zip ./*` should work.

Comment: It still zips from the top directory strangely enough...